# Get Forge App access token by manual triggering in Power Automate using V2 Authentication

Tags: authentication, autodesk-forge, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I followed someone's advice for using v2 of forge authentication for my forge app to get access token using a manual trigger in Power Automate.

here is the screen shot but still getting the error of "The client_id specified does not have access to the api product"

Here is the power automate step

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaPBv.png)

I have tried all the bellow different authorization code

Basic PE9KUDVUSE9UUDh0R05PZEV6YzNhWmZTTUtvUkRvZmdVPjo8eVdJTm12eHZ2WDEzWFFKSj****==

Basic <PE9KUDVUSE9UUDh0R05PZEV6YzNhWmZTTUtvUkRvZmdVPjo8eVdJTm12eHZ2WDEzWFFKSj****==>

Concat('Basic ', PE9KUDVUSE9UUDh0R05PZEV6YzNhWmZTTUtvUkRvZmdVPjo8eVdJTm12eHZ2WDEzWFFKSj****==)

Comment: The authorization code should be in the format "Basic <client_id>:<client_secret>".

Answer (score 0):

The error means: either the category product (such as BIM360, Model Derivative etc) is not selected when you created your Forge app. You can see how to enable the APIs you want your application to have access to in the page https://tutorials.autodesk.io/

The error might also mean that you are trying to call some APIs which have not been exposed officially (in private beta which requires whitelist). It would be helpful to diagnose if you could tell us which API endpoints throw the error so that we can help.